# Go to first line of console output of a command

Tags: shell, terminal, output

Let's say I am calling `ls -la`, which produces a very long output. Is there any key/command which lets my console scroll up to the first line of the output?

Comment: what console are we talking about? Serial? Virtual? screen/tmux? XWindow (gnome/xterm/etc)? [reference](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132/117549)

Comment: Maybe a teletype?     :-)    ⁠

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the output is **very** long you could use the `less` command like below:

```
your_command_here | less
```

And then scroll all the way down by pressing keys like Enter, Space etc.
For more see the [less manpage](http://ss64.com/bash/less.html).

You could even use `more`

```
you_command_here | more
```

`more` works like `less` but uses different key combinations to page through the text. For more see the [more manpage](http://ss64.com/bash/more.html).

Now you might remember that very old quote :

> **less** is **more**

Comment: More important in my opinion is the fact that `more` doesn't let you go *backward* in the text, while `less` *does*.  With `more` once you page down you can't go back.

Comment: Not true, actually. You can use the CTRL^B key sequence in `more` to go backwards in an output buffer, as long as you haven't scrolled past the end of the buffer, itself.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS, iTerm version 3 beta can do this using a hotkey, if you enable shell integration: http://iterm2.com/features.html#shell-integration

Answer (score 0):

If you know your output size to scroll past one screenful, i.e., more than say 22 lines or so, it is upon you to plan against such incidence and set a method to buffer the output. This can be done simply setting the scroll-back buffer size of your terminal emulator, if it supports such thing and use the side bars to scroll up and down. Or better direct the `stdout` and `stderr` to file(s) for future inspection, either using redirection, `>` or `>>` or pipe the output to a `tee file_name` command.

Operating systems, at least the UNIX/Linux flavors that I deal with, don't provide a command to scroll up and down in the screen buffer, other than `less` and variants, which requires you to be prepared for such event, before you run your command. Sorry.